# 2D to 3D face reconstruction using OpenGL

Tags: image-processing, opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, face-recognition

Can anyone tell me how to implement 2D to 3D face reconstruction in OpenGL

I am new to 3D Graphics and rendering. Can anyone tell me how to do 2D to 3D face reconstruction from 2D image. What are the algorithms used and how can it be done using OpenGL? Related functions.

Input: 2D frontal face image

Output: 3D reconstruction of the input

Comment: This is far too broad a question. [Computer vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision) is a *hard* problem, covering many different fields.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes. The problem is an interesting and hard one and solving it would have a lot of practical uses. I do agree though, that the question as stated by OP is verly broad and impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone tell me how to implement 2D to 3D face reconstruction in OpenGL

You can't. OpenGL is a 3D rasterizer drawing API. It's used to turn 3D geometry into 2D pictures, i.e. goes in the opposite direction of what you want to do.

> Input: 2D frontal face image
>
> Output: 3D reconstruction of the input

*This is the real world, not CSI!*

You need at least some additional input to turn this into 3D data. Each pixel of the image is a point in 2D space, i.e. provides 2 variables into an equation. You want to turn this into 3 variables. Or in other words, this is an underdetermined system of equations.

Additional input could be:

- Time: If you had a movie, then by the movements of the visible objects over time their position in space can be inferred.
- Images from multiple angles
- Taking the picture with special illumination, so that the pixel's color provides additional information about the depth.

[Research on this has been done at the University of Washington](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/). I recommend looking at all their papers!

An trained observer model, i.e. what our brain does to infer objects depth in a 2D picture is very unreliable. Just look at any arbitrary [perspective illusion](http://images.google.com/search?num=10&q=perspective%20illusion&oq=perspective%20illusion) to understand why. Our brain is much better in interpreting images than any computer program and still can be fooled.

Comment: @ dantenwolf :: Thanks for the link and answer... Can you refer me any codes in C and OpenGL. I have understood the 3D to 2D part you said - 3D Graphics Rendering Pipeline... I am going through the univ link...

Comment: @2vision2: IMHO the best resource to start OpenGL these days is Nicol Bolas' tutorial at http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut – it's the only tutorial that is not only to the point, but also gives a lot of useful background information, why things in OpenGL are like they are.